# (Unusual proof) Proof that a sequence of functions converges to a function via Induction.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, sequence-of-function

I came across a rather unusual proof but I’m not sure if it is correct or incorrect. I want to prove that, for a sequence of functions  $f_n:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,1]$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\quad f_n(x)=f(x)$$

I found a proof by induction on $x$. Since the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ they prove that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\quad f_n(0)=f(0)$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\quad f_n(1)=f(1)$$

And then suppose that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\quad f_n(k)=f(k)$$

holds. Then it is just left to prove that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\quad f_n(k+1)=f(k+1)$$

Can you give the arguments why this is correct or incorrect?

Comment: not knowing anything about fn one can not say anything, but if the first steps are true the form of the proof is ok

Comment: Edited. Thanks! How can you argue that the proof is ok? Supposing the first steps are true.

Comment: Let $S = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(k) = f(k)\}$. Then it's the usual induction proof that $S = \mathbb{N}$, i.e. one starts with proving $0 \in S$, and then goes on with $k \in S \implies (k+1) \in S$.

Comment: This is just the usual procedure for induction .